# Find current page and forces it to refresh / reload

Tags: flutter

When I received a notification from messaging services (like firebase), how can I tell which page it is displaying now, and forces it to refresh (or reload)?

Comment: Hi, did u find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

May be what you want is:

```dart
ModalRoute.of(context).isCurrent
```